# SPLADE: Unable to update value of <x-splade-input> using javascript

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to create a input with suggestions based on text input, using javascript to do the same

```
 var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destinationInput');
 var destinationDropdownContainer = document.getElementById('destinationOptions');
  destinationInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
                    var inputText = destinationInput.value;
                    if (inputText.length >= 3) {
                        fetchAutocompleteResults(inputText,destinationInput,                 destinationDropdownContainer);
                    } else {
                        destinationDropdownContainer.innerHTML = '';
                    }
                });

function fetchAutocompleteResults(inputText,input, dropdownContainer) {
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                            displayAutocompleteResults(data,input, dropdownContainer);
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.open('GET', '/search/airport/' + encodeURIComponent(inputText), true);
                    xhr.send();
                }

                function displayAutocompleteResults(results, input, dropdownContainer) {
                    dropdownContainer.innerHTML = '';

                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        var option = document.createElement('div');
                        option.className = 'dropdown-option';
                        option.textContent = results[i];
                        dropdownContainer.appendChild(option);
                    }

                    var dropdownOptions = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-option');
                    for (var j = 0; j < dropdownOptions.length; j++) {
                        dropdownOptions[j].addEventListener('click', function() {
                            input.value = this.textContent;
                            dropdownContainer.innerHTML = '';
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```

After this clicking on the suggestion does update the value of input but as soon as I change anything else on the form or submit the form the value will revert back to the string that was entered while searching.

tried using  also but it does not support dynamic searching based on its own input.

[image: Suggestions based on the input]
Even after selecting the suggested item from the list on form submission or updating any other field on the form it reverts back to the searched string
[image: Only getting searched sting in the request]